# Adsense and blocking robots from web pages

Tags: google-adsense, robots.txt, meta-tags

If I use a meta tag to make a page 'noindex' does this mean that my adsense ads will not be targeted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adsense bot crawls irrespective of the "noindex" tag. Adsense bot has no relation with the web crawler that logs website information. Adsense bot can work without any conflict with the noindex tag on the page.